# Can @CachePut annotation be put for createOrUpdate method?

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cache

I had a small doubt -

I have a method in my service layer that either creates a record if that ID isnt present or updates record if it is.  Can i just put @CachePut annotation on the method? Or Should I also put @Cacheable anotation also on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to use `@CachePut` on your service method performing the create or update.  For example...

Assuming...

```
class Customer {

  @Id
  Long id;

  ...
}
```

And given...

```
@Service
class CustomerService {

  CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  @CachePut("Customers", key="#customer.id")
  Customer createOrUpdate(Customer customer) {
    // validate customer
    // any business logic or pre-save operations
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
  }
}
```

`@Cacheable` is going perform a **look-aside** in the named cache before executing `createOrUpdate(:Customer)`.  If the Customer with ID already exists in the named cache, then Spring will return the "cached" `Customer`; Spring will not execute the create/update method in that case.

However, if the identified `Customer` does not exist (or is invalid), Spring proceeds to execute the `createOrUpdate(:Customer)` method and then cache the result of the method.

In the `@CachePut` case, Spring will always execute the `createOrUpdate(:Customer)` method.  That is, Spring will not perform a look-aside to determine whether the Customer exists before executing the method, which is most likely what you want in the case of a create/update.

Anyway, more information about declarative based Caching can be found in the [Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations).  In particular, have a look at the [`@CachePut` docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-put) and compare that with the [`@Cacheable` docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable).

Hope this helps!
-John

Comment: if the  `Long id` is private and I have getters and setters that are public, then do I have to put `key="#customer.getId()"` ?

Comment: so It accesses the primitives in the object by Reflections? Cool thanks.
Anyways - `getId` also worked just fine